Oracle Apex How to use date column in item filters
I have an Interactive grid:
select emp_id, emp_name, joining_date from employees 
where (:P1_EMP_NAME ='All' or :P1_EMP_NAME !='All' and emp_name=:P1_EMP_NAME);

On top of it i have a filter.
P1_EMP_NAME-> Select list->
select emp_name d, emp_id store from employees;

The EMP_NAME search is already configured.
I have FIND button which on click submits the P1_EMP_NAME item and refreshes grid..
I need to configure similar filter using joining_date: P1_JOINING_DATE.
But i want to understand how do i dispaly dates in item and how can i configure in query such that the date selected filter IG query accordingly?

Do you simply want to include the next filter using AND like this: select emp_id, emp_name, joining_date from employees  where (:P1_EMP_NAME ='All' or emp_name=:P1_EMP_NAME) AND (:P1_JOINING_DATE IS NULL OR joining_date = :P1_JOINING_DATE);?

As an aside, :P1_EMP_NAME !='All' is redundant in your query and can be removed without affecting the logic.

Yes but the page item: P1_JOINING_DATE-> Should this be date? Since joining_date is date column

Page items do not have a "data type" that maps to the database data types. All page items are strings in a browser context. A page item like "Number field" just ensures the browser renders the correct directives for a number field but it doesn't really map to the NUMBER data type. The values that is passed from the html page is implicitely or explicitly casted to the correct datatype by the apex engine.
If you have a page item that contains a date, then it's advised to do a TO_DATE(:P1_PAGE_ITEM,'<your_date_format') in the query to ensure that the bind variable is correctly interpreted as date.

I tried but it doesn't return anything when i click find.. What should i keep the page item format as then? and  should it be date picker or text?

what is the data type of the column JOINING_DATE ?
and how do the date values look like? dd/mm/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss
perhaps you may need to do trunc(JOINING_DATE) = :P1_DATE

datatype is DATE.. Format is DD-MON-RR

OK the trunc part worked... Thanks!!

well it was just for observation, it may mess your index up if there is any.

ok, one more thing. What should i put as default value for the item? For Employee its All..Right now its coming as selected so even if no date is selected it should return all rows

WHERE trunc(JOINING_DATE) = :P1_DATE OR :P1_DATE IS NULL will return all rows if there is no value. Is that what you want ?

I would say joining_date = nvl(:p1_date, joining_date)

@Oguen Using joining_date = nvl(:p1_date, joining_date) will not match rows when joining_date is NULL. This may not be a problem if the column is NOT NULL but, as a generic solution for other people, it has that limitation.

A DATE has both date- and time-components so to match an instant use (changing the date format to your required format):
select emp_id, emp_name, joining_date
from   employees 
where  (  :P1_EMP_NAME ='All'
       or emp_name=:P1_EMP_NAME
       )
AND    (  :P1_JOINING_DATE IS NULL
       OR joining_date = TO_DATE(:P1_JOINING_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
       );

or if your joining_date values always have a midnight time-component then:
select emp_id, emp_name, joining_date
from   employees 
where  (  :P1_EMP_NAME ='All'
       or emp_name=:P1_EMP_NAME
       )
AND    (  :P1_JOINING_DATE IS NULL
       OR joining_date = TO_DATE(:P1_JOINING_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
       );


If you want to match an entire day then use (again, changing the format to match your requirements):
select emp_id, emp_name, joining_date
from   employees 
where  (  :P1_EMP_NAME ='All'
       or emp_name=:P1_EMP_NAME
       )
AND    (  :P1_JOINING_DATE IS NULL
       OR (   joining_date >= TO_DATE(:P1_JOINING_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
          AND joining_date <  TO_DATE(:P1_JOINING_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
                              + INTERVAL '1' DAY
          )
       );

or:
select emp_id, emp_name, joining_date
from   employees 
where  (  :P1_EMP_NAME ='All'
       or emp_name=:P1_EMP_NAME
       )
AND    (  :P1_JOINING_DATE IS NULL
       OR TRUNC(joining_date) = TO_DATE(:P1_JOINING_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
       );

Note: this last option would not use an index on joining_date and would need a separate function-based index on TRUNC(joining_date).
